# search by category ONLY in Magento

Tags: magento, search, magento-1.7

I have a drop down menu and a keyword text field. the drop down menu is filled with categories I made for products. I want to know how I can search products without having to input anything in the keyword text field. In other words I would like to allow my magento search to search by category only too.

I tried and revised the Query resource and it worked sometime before. after I committed it to our repository it failed to work.

```
public function loadByQuery(Mage_Core_Model_Abstract $object, $value)
{
    $select = $this->_getReadAdapter()->select()
        ->from($this->getMainTable())
        // ->where('synonym_for=? OR query_text=?', $value)
        ->where('query_text like("%'.$value.'%")')
        ->where('store_id=?', $object->getStoreId())
        ->order('synonym_for ASC')
        ->limit(1);
    if ($data = $this->_getReadAdapter()->fetchRow($select)) {
        $object->setData($data);
        $this->_afterLoad($object);
    }

    return $this;
}
```

Comment: do you want to implement search by category in magento? if yes then i can help you bcz i have implemented the same in home page.

Comment: yes i do. The thing is I have a search in my magento front end it works perfectly well but it can't search if I don't put anything in the keyword field

Comment: Are you using magento quick search or advance search? And keyword means you are telling about quick search right?

Comment: yes quick search it is :D

Comment: If u don't put anything in the keyword then on which basis it will search? In one of my project i removed validation from the quick search and added onblur functionality as well. If keyword is empty then it is search by 'Search entire store here...' text.

Comment: if I do not put anything in the keyword then it should search using the categories dropdown. Is there any way?

Comment: To implement search by category in magento mini search visit   http://just4help.info/add-category-list-on-search-form-in-magento/ OR http://xhtmlandcsshelp.blogspot.in/2011/11/search-by-category-in-magento.html